# Error while updating nested field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

Hi i am using elasticsearch java API for updating a document with script. But i am getting below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" MapperParsingException[object mapping for [content] tried to parse field [content] as object, but found a concrete value]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObject(DocumentParser.java:215)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObjectOrField(DocumentParser.java:308)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseValue(DocumentParser.java:438)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObject(DocumentParser.java:264)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseDocument(DocumentParser.java:124)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:309)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.prepareIndex(IndexShard.java:580)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.prepareIndexOnPrimary(IndexShard.java:559)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.prepareIndexOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:211)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.executeIndexRequestOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:223)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:157)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:66)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryPhase.doRun(TransportReplicationAction.java:657)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryOperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportReplicationAction.java:287)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryOperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportReplicationAction.java:279)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:77)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4.doRun(TransportService.java:376)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Below is the existing document in the ES

```
{
  "_index": "index1",
  "_type": "type1",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 8,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "content": {
      "contentId": 1,
      "metadata": {
        "title": "content one",
        "duration": 4500
      }
    },
    "custom": {
      "field1": "value1"
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to update the "content" field as below

```
"content": {
      "contentId": 1,
      "metadata": {
        "duration": 900
      }
    }
```

when i am updating with REST call (localhost:9200/index1/type1/1/_update), it is working fine. I am getting error in java API prepareUpdate.

I have 3 java classes.
DTO class has Content object
Content class has Metadata object and contentId as long
Metadata class has title (String) and duration(long).

Below is the code to update

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("contentScript", dto.toString());
Script s = new Script("ctx._source.content=contentScript",ScriptType.INLINE,null,params);
UpdateResponse resp = client.prepareUpdate("index1", "type1", "1").setScript(s).setScriptedUpsert(true).get();
```

dto is object of DTO class and values are set accordingly.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
params.put("contentScript", dto.toString());
```

You are passing a string where it is expecting an object. The below code might help.

```
String script = "ctx._source.pete = jsonMap";
Map<String, Object> jsonMap = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, HashMap.class);
Map<String, Object> params = ImmutableMap.of("jsonMap", jsonMap);
return new Script(script, ScriptService.ScriptType.INLINE, null, params);
```

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-update-nested-objects-in-elasticsearch-2-2-script-via-java-api/43135/2

Comment: This worked. But even though i am putting the dto object or json string in the params map, it is giving same error. Only HashMap object is working fine.